# `CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the namespace `UnitySampleAssets'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, namespaces

When importing the [Standard Assets for Unity 4.6](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21064) package to my Unity 4 project, I receive the following error:

> Assets/SampleAssets/2D/Scripts/Platformer2DUserControl.cs(2,25): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the namespace`UnitySampleAssets'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

Comment: Add error messages as **text** inside the question. Do not link screenshots. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be solved by importing all of the CrossPlatformInput assets. When importing, I suspect you are not check marking all of the boxes.

Specifically, make sure to checkmark the CrossPlatformInput folder during asset import.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I Know it's 4 years ago , but i hop i can save any one a little bit of time

here is the solution, All you need is to make sure that the script (with the error) is in the same folder with Cross platform scripts. that worked with me
and make sure you delete the script from ur gameobject and update it with the new one

[Like the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgsPC.png)

Answer (score -1):

In your project folder there should be other folder in the name of `StandardAsset` & 
`CrossPlatform`. Since `CrossPlatform` is not imported, you need to delete other files and try again.